# div overflow scroll: when scrolled to bottom, content starts scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I have a modal dialog with a scrollable div inside. The div is set to

```
overflow: scroll;
```

However, when the user scrolls all the way down inside the div, the content behind the popup starts scrolling down.

**Question:** When the popup is open, I don't want the user to be able to scroll the main page behind it. Is this possible?

I don't think there is need for me to provide code, as this is a very general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery set css as

```
overflow: hidden
```

when popup is open

and on popup close use

`overflow : auto` or `overflow : scroll` as you wish.

I think, I don't need to write code for it.

Comment: So very simple and effective. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting  the property for the body `overflow: hidden`  when pop up opens and `overflow: hidden` when popup closes.